# jQuery date range slider - how to increase decrease range

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone point me to a working plugin of this kind:

[date range slider with plus minus buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ9l6.png)

I am not a developer, but the developers in my organisation say it's rather difficult to achieve. So if there is a plugin of this sort somewhere, I could just point it out to them!

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: 1st: Welcome to Stackoverflow. 2nd: From what i see(which isn't much: a code snippet of the relevant functions or even a DOM excerpt would be much appreciated) this isn't really a hard problem _but_ that strongly depends on the implementation... the first thing you could try is figure out if the value that you want to change is stored in some variable/configuration or if it's just a magic number somewhere in the code since this will determine how hard it would be to change the current behavior of the software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JqRangeSlider.
Here is the link for download that library
Link-http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html

Sample Code for this plugin

```
<!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jQDateRangeSlider-min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<!--
      $("#slider").dateRangeSlider();
    //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```